# Passing different sys.argv to the same docker run port

Tags: python, docker, flask, deployment, containers

I wanted to pass in system variables to `docker run` wanting to use the same port, the python/flask code will be something like this:

```
a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
c = sys.argv[3]

@app.route('/')

def run():
    return function.do(a, b, c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

In the command line I passed in this line:
`docker run -p 5000:5000 <imageName> "A" "AB" "ABC"`. However in the first run I'm able to get the output showing in `localhost:5000`, but the second try it will say the port is allocated. Am I able to use the same 5000 port without killing the container process?

I guess the workaround will be using different ports like `-p 5001:5000` and `-p 5002:5000` and so on. I was just wondering if there is any way to only use one port? Maybe it's a Flask problem?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can avoid to map the port 5000 on the host.

Comment: You can't have two processes or containers listening on the same (host) port, no matter what.  You can map the second container to a different host port `-p 5001:5000`, or stop the first container, or otherwise avoid the port conflict.